# Loading and rendered state component Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

I'm trying to create a reusable **PageContainer component that only renders the child component after data is loaded**. I created a slot in the component for the child component(s) to be rendered after the data is fetched but it seems like the components in the slot ignores the v-if. Does anyone have a better suggestion on how to do this?

My vuex state is structured like so

```js
state: {
   // before fetch set, set loading = true
   // after receiving data, set loading = false and data = result.data
   carts: { loading: false, error: false, data: undefined },
}
```

PageContainer.vue

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="isLoading">
      <v-progress-circular :size="80" :width="7" color="primary" indeterminate></v-progress-circular>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="isError">
      <div>error</div>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Errored out because `carts.data` is undefined

View.vue

```html
<template>
  <PageContainer :isLoading="carts.loading" :isError="carts.error">
    <div>{{ carts.data.name }}</div>
  </PageContainer>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the cart is stored in vuex store, you access it by calling

```
this.$store.state.carts
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `computed` section to get the datas from your store:

```
computed: {
        getCarts(){
          return this.$store.state.carts
        }
      }
```

right now update your template:

```
<PageContainer :isLoading="getCarts.loading" :isError="getCarts.error">
    <div>{{ getCarts.data.name }}</div>
  </PageContainer>
```